# Change the output language of WeekStart in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, multilingual

I'm using a calendar layout in Excel, and the start of the week (monday) is given by the function WeekStart. However, English is not my native tongue and I want to change the names of the weeks and months. I have managed to achieve this by adding a language code snippet in the code before the other days of the week/months, but no combination seems to work with the function WeekStart.

I'm sorry for clumsy writing, I really don't know how to express this specific problem properly because I am not even entirely sure how this function works. I've added an image for illustration. This is the template that I'm using https://templates.office.com/en-US/Evergreen-calendar-tabs-white-TM00000047 .

Thanks in advance.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqL3k.png)

Comment: Just create yourself a lookup table to convert the result of the weekstart function to what you want it to be ie Monday to Lundi, Tuesday to Mardi etc

Comment: @SolarMike how do I create a lookup table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you could, if your weekstart function is in cell A1, then in cell B2 have:

```
=vlookup(A1,A5:B11,2,0)
```

With the days in A5:A11 as Monday to Sunday and in B5:B11 the days you want to change to.

[image]